# Updating row based on previous row to provide a running total

Tags: ms-access

I have Customer table in Microsoft access with data as follows:

```
CustID  Debit   Credit  Balance
1       0       3000    -3000
1       3000    0       0
1       0       200     200
2       0       300     500
3       0       400     900
1       500     0       400
```

what I need is to recalculate the balance column if any update happens in debit or credit based on the equation (balance=previousbalance+credit-debit) , and this is done for a given customer id.
I searched and found that there is no lead and lag as in sql.

Comment: Does that table have any other column(s) that will uniquely identify each row and indicate the order in which the transactions occurred?

Comment: yeah I have a primary key auto number, sorry I forgot to mention it

Comment: Why does the first row for CustID 1 have a Balance of -3000?

Comment: these data was after running my own query, and unfortunately it gave me wrong values. debit and credit are correct values but the balance is what I need to recalculate based on my equation. I hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say that you have a table named [Transactions] with your sample data and an `AutoNumber` field named [ID]:

```
ID  CustID  Debit  Credit  Balance
--  ------  -----  ------  -------
 1       1      0    3000    -3000
 2       1   3000       0        0
 3       1      0     200      200
 4       2      0     300      500
 5       3      0     400      900
 6       1    500       0      400
```

The new [Balance] for each row is `SUM(Credit) - SUM(Debit)` for that [CustID] where [ID] is less than or equal to the current [ID]. So one way of accomplishing that would be to use an UPDATE query like this one

```sql
UPDATE Transactions
SET [Balance] = 
        DSum("Credit", "Transactions", "CustID=" & [CustID] & " AND ID<=" & [ID])
            - DSum("Debit", "Transactions", "CustID=" & [CustID] & " AND ID<=" & [ID])
```

After we run that query our [Balance] figures look like this:

```
ID  CustID  Debit  Credit  Balance
--  ------  -----  ------  -------
 1       1      0    3000     3000
 2       1   3000       0        0
 3       1      0     200      200
 4       2      0     300      300
 5       3      0     400      400
 6       1    500       0     -300
```

Comment: thank you Mr Gord , your query is perfectly correct, but this is not totally what I need. you query updates all the records, and I want to update only the set of records of a certain customer id. I tried to replace [CustID] with 1, it also updated the whole records.

Comment: ok I added the criteria to the query and not to the dsum function like this 
UPDATE Test
SET [Balance] = 
        DSum("Credit", "Test", "CustID=" & [CustID] & " AND ID<=" & [ID])- DSum("Debit", "Test", "CustID=" & [CustID] & " AND ID<=" & [ID]) where CustID=1